# Invalid signature for user or client

Tags: ruby, chef-recipe, devops, knife

we created a cookbook locally on the computer with the command: knife create cookbook web in powershell, and we want to upload it to the chef server with command: knife cookbook upload web and it gives us an error:ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://api.chef.io/organizations/e_t as e_t with key C:/chef-repo/.chef/e_t.pem Response:  **Invalid signature for user or client** 'e_t' , what is the problem??? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [Chef node configuration issue with knife bootstrap- can't authenticate with server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561129/chef-node-configuration-issue-with-knife-bootstrap-cant-authenticate-with-serv)

Are sure your pem file is valid?

take a look at the chef docs about [public/private keys](https://docs.chef.io/chef_private_keys.html):